# Simplify $(i \theta)^n+(- i \theta)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need help simplifying this:

> $(i \theta)^n+(- i \theta)^n$ with the sum going from $n=0$ to $n=\infty$
>   This is part of this,
>   sum from n=0 to infinity of (1/4) 2^n((I theta)^n + (-I theta$^n))/n! +(1/2) and I want to simplify this to show the maclaurin series for cos^2(z)

Comment: Consider series for $\frac{1}{\theta i + 1}$

Comment: not sure I tried doing( i^n theta^n)+((-I)^n theta^n) but after that not sure

Comment: Actaully can we simplify without the sum?

Comment: @Guest Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

- What happens when $n$ is odd? What about when it is even? Simplify the term.
- Geometric series.

Alternatively work on two sums separately and then sum them up later.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$n=1\implies (i \theta)+(- i \theta)=0$

$n=2\implies (- \theta^2)+(- \theta^2)=-2\theta^2$

$n=3\implies (-i \theta^3)+(i \theta^3)=0$

$n=4\implies (\theta^4)+(\theta^4)=2\theta^4$

...

thus, we can prove by induction, that

- for $n$ odd $(i \theta)^n+(- i \theta)^n =0$
- for $n$ even $(i \theta)^n+(- i \theta)^n =2(-\theta^2)^{n/2}$

thus set n=2k and calculate the

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2(-\theta^2)^{k}$$

by geometric series.

Comment: Ok thanks so but if I have a sum in front, how can I like write for odds or even separately? Thanks!

Comment: Also this is part of a cos^2(z) maclaurin series expansion proof. So are there two cases for this series?

Comment: But I also have 2^n((I theta)^n+(-I theta)^n)/n!. So 2^n/n!. Can I simplify this also?

Comment: Sorry, you should show the full text in the OP.

Comment: Yeah so it's like sum from n=0 to infinity of (1/4) 2^n((I theta)^n + (-I theta$^n))/n! +(1/2) and I want to simplify this to show its the maclaurin series expansion for cos^2(z)

Comment: Add the full problem in the OP, it will be more vlear.